# Simplenews - how pass values from own input

Tags: forms, emails

How I can pass value from added input to database(?) in Simplenews? I want to use this value later in newsletter, e.g. print it in block template.

Below is how I created field

```
function news_hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 'simplenews_block_form_2730'){
        $form['field_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('First name'),
        '#required' => TRUE,  
        '#size' => 20,  
);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    $form['field_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Name'),
    );
    $form['field_name_submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('SAVE'),
      '#submit' => array('my_module_name_submit'),
    );
  return $form;
  }
}

function my_module_name_submit($form,&$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['field_name']) {
    variable_set('Name', $form_state['values']['field_name']);
  }
}
```

[variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) stores textfield value in `variable table`. You can access/get this value using [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) as mentioned below

> variable_get('Name')

Comment: hmm but now I have two submit buttons - one from Simplenews module, and second created by alter_form. There's no option which can link or something my values to module's submit button? Moreover - I can hide Simplenew's submit button, but this created button will not pass other values (e.g. from e-mail field originally rendered by module) and mailing won't work :C

Comment: You can get the values using **variable_get**,  which can be used anywhere